# Flutter swipe to sides like in chrome

Tags: flutter, swipe-gesture

In my book-like Flutter app, there is a requirement to swipe in horizontal direction in order to navigate to previous and next page. I looked for a package which does something like that in [pub.dev](http://pub.dev/) and didn't find. I'd like to know if there is already something like that to not-invent a wheel. If not, I'd like to hear (not excepting you to make it for me) what approach can be taken in order to implement it by myself.

[image: chrome side swipe]

Comment: I guess you are looking for this package
[swipedetector](https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the PageView widget. Just provide the pages, the swiping functionality is built-in.

```
PageView(
  controller: _controller,
  children: [
    MyPage1Widget(),
    MyPage2Widget(),
    MyPage3Widget(),
  ],
)
```

Since you're saying it's for a book which likely has a lot of pages you might want to use PageView.builder() instead of better performance.

There's a more information about the widget [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-pageview-widget-e0f6c8092636)

Comment: As mentioned, I looked at pub.dev, but didn't think that a standard component might exists... I took my lesson. It works great with PageView.builder. thanks.